# Cannot install ROS noetic's nmea_msgs through Chocolatey on Windows

Tags: ros-noetic

I have successfully installed ROS on Windows and my project is depending on nmea_msgs package. However, when using chocolatey to install nmea_msgs, it failed to find the package.

Command ran:

```
choco install ros-noetic-nmea-msgs
```

Result:

````
Chocolatey v2.0.0
Chocolatey detected you are not running from an elevated command shell
 (cmd/powershell).

 You may experience errors - many functions/packages
 require admin rights. Only advanced users should run choco w/out an
 elevated shell. When you open the command shell, you should ensure
 that you do so with "Run as Administrator" selected. If you are
 attempting to use Chocolatey in a non-administrator setting, you
 must select a different location other than the default install
 location. See
 https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/setup#non-administrative-install
 for details.


 Do you want to continue?([Y]es/[N]o): y

Installing the following packages:
ros-noetic-nmea-msgs
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
ros-noetic-nmea-msgs not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://aka.ms/ros/public;https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (c:\opt\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - ros-noetic-nmea-msgs - ros-noetic-nmea-msgs not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://aka.ms/ros/public;https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.
```
````

Answer (score 0):

There aren't as many binary-installable packages on Windows/Chocolatey compared with what's available via `apt` on Linux. However, the `nmea_msgs` package is a simple message package with basic dependencies, so it should be straightforward to clone the repo and build it in a Catkin workspace:

https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_msgs

It looks like you should check out the `master` branch to build the package for Noetic.